# Creating a custom tomcat session manager without putting the jar in the CATALINA_HOME directory?

Tags: session, tomcat, context.xml

I am working on a custom session manager for Tomcat and I got it working with one caveat, I have to put the jar(and all the associated jars) in the CATALINA_HOME/lib directory or I get a noclassdef found exception, even though the classes are in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Is there any way to force tomcat to look in the web apps lib directory when it is loading a session manager?  Putting it in the lib directory is error-prone(as you have to remember to copy the jar over when upgrading and/or installing on a new system) and makes development of the jar more difficult.

Comment: I'm not good in Java, just my 2 cents. If session manager is consumed by tomcat rather than a specific context, it should deploy in the classpath that tomcat use, not a specific context's classpath. Am I correct?

Comment: To be clear, I am not defining the manager in the Tomcat servers context.xml, I am defining it in my applications context.xml, so I would imagine that the WEB-INF/lib directory should be loaded before that is parsed(or at least before the manager bit is parsed) but that does not seem to be the case....  But then again I am by no means a Tomcat or even webapp expert, so I could be totally wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Tomcat 7.0.27, the <Manager> element in your `META-INF/context.xml` file is processed by the commons-digester and the effective ClassLoader is set to that which loaded the ContextConfig class -- one which firmly resides in Tomcat's server ClassLoader, which is outside of the ClassLoading chain of anything with access to the webapp's classes.

So, without modifying the Tomcat source, there will be no way to load your `Manager` from within your webapp. Consider joining the Tomcat users' mailing list to discuss such a feature.

**EDIT 2015-067-01**

If you want to specify a `ClassLoader` for your web application, you'll need to use the `<Loader>` element within your `<Context>`: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/loader.html

Comment: Can you please link to what you're referencing?

Comment: The answer is helpful. It would just be nice to have a link to where the manager's classloader choice is documented. I couldn't find it in the change log.

Comment: Added a link to the `<Loader>` documentation. It's not in the ChangeLog because it was never changed... it's been a feature for a good long time.